# Remove unwanted python packages from linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pip

I have a server with CentOS installed on it. Python 2.6.6 was installed on it. I installed python 3.4.2 and 2.7.8. Now when i use command like :

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

it's stop with error and error is for using different packages. How can i remove other packages and have just python 3.4.2? 
Sorry for my terrible English.

Comment: This my [error](http://textuploader.com/oc3x)

Comment: pip3 install virtualenvwrapper

Comment: -bash: pip3: command not found

Comment: Maybe you can try `yum install python3-setuptools` and `easy_install3 pip`

Comment: don't use `pip` for Python 2.6 if you want to install packages for Python 3.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to uninstall a package through `pip`, you can try

```
pip uninstall <package>
```

More details can be found [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip_uninstall.html)